# iPad video in portrait mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, cocos2d-iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have made an `iPad video` in `portrait mode` i.e. `768*1024`. Now when I convert it in `mp4` format the converter converts it into `1024*768` i.e `landscape mode`.Is there any way to show the portrait video in portrait mode or any software to convert the portrait video in mp4 portrait mode?

or I would have to make the video again in landscape mode?

I am using `MPMoviePlayerController`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you're creating video or converting the video?...i dont see a single of line of coding..paste the coding part so that we can understand what you're trying to do..any private API you are using?

Answer (score 0):

**MPMoviePlayerController** no longer works in **landscape** by default so to make it work in landscape you need to apply a transform to the view.

```
UIView * playerView = [moviePlayerController view];
[playerView setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)];//iPhone

CGAffineTransform landscapeTransform;
landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(90*M_PI/180.0f);
landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(landscapeTransform, 80, 80);

[playerView setTransform: landscapeTransform];
In addition, if you want the regular full screen controls, use the following sample.

moviePlayerController.fullscreen = TRUE;
moviePlayerController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
```

This is for your information "[**playing a video with MPMoviePlayerController in Portrait WITHOUT Private API-Will get rejected by Apple**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452540/playing-a-video-with-mpmovieplayercontroller-in-portrait-without-private-api-w)".Good luck and happy coding :-)